# Getting "Cannot read property 'of' of undefined" using angular 8, and httpclient

Tags: angular, http, httpclient, angular-httpclient

I have configured my project with new `httpclient` using following service. 
AppModule.ts is setup correctly

```
getAllLocosByID(locoID: string) {
    return this.http.get<Search[]>(`${environment.apiUrl.searchbylocoid}/${locoID}`);
}
```

Also Search is set to be

```
export class Search {
    input: string;
    warningMessages: String[];
    errorMessages: String[];
    numFound: number;
    results: String[];
    APP_CODE: string;
}
```

on my component I have

```
logoSearchResults: Search[];
constructor(private data: DataAccessService) { }    
getLocmotives() {
    this.data.getAllLocosByID('A1').subscribe((res: Search[]) => {
    // console.log(Array.of(res));
    // console.log(typeof (response));
    // this.logoSearchResults = res;
    this.logoSearchResults = { ...res };
    console.log(this.logoSearchResults);
 },
  error => {
    console.log("error");
  })
}
```

which gives me following on the browser console. Based on httpclient documents returning response is already an observable json which I am forming it to a `Search[]`

```
{input: "A1", warningMessages: Array(0), errorMessages: Array(0), numFound: 241, results: Array(3), …}
```

So far, so good!. but lets put it on HTML part, and show it to the end user

I put a button on the HTML that works with click

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getLocmotives()">
   Give me answer
</button>
{{ logoSearchResults }}
```

This is what I get on screen from `{{ logoSearchResults }}`

```
[object object]
```

by updating HTML codes to loop through this array to

```
<ul class="list-group">
  {{ logoSearchResults }}
  <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let result of logoSearchResults">
     {{ result }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am getting following error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

By updating HTML codes to

```
<ul class="list-group">
 {{ logoSearchResults }}
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let result of Array.of(logoSearchResults)">
    {{ result }}
 </li>
```

I am getting following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'of' of undefined
```

What should I do in HTML or angular part to be able to show my data on scree?

Comment: In the template you say `...of Array.of(...`, but a `this` is always implied. Therefore it's parsed as `this.Array.of(logoSearchResults)`, and since you don't have a `this.Array` inside the accompanying TS's scope - undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add an array to ngfor: *ngFor="let result of logoSearchResults.results"

Comment: I am getting result on screen. So far, most accurate answer to this question, but I am still getting this error on the console before clicking on `Give me answer`. Cannot read property 'results' of undefined. Do you have a solution for it?

Comment: yes, since it is not initialized use this: *ngFor="let result of logoSearchResults?.results"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<pre>{{ logoSearchResults | json}}</pre>
```

**json pipe** will show you your exact json.

**< pre >** will also align json so its readable.

Comment: interesting that json pipe has helped to show it screen,  thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its this line that’s the problem
this.logoSearchResults = { ...res };
Your putting the res into an object. You can’t loop with of on a object. And I see that you service

```
this.http.get<Search[]>
```

should return an Array of Search so you should have

```
this.logoSearchResult=res;
```

And in your loop change to

```
{{ result|json }}
```

Comment: with @jens solution in place, and using spread operator {...res} or not using it gives a same result. my assumption is res is an object which is true based on httpclient document

Comment: update will cause this error " Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Then your res (response) is not an array. Please show your console.log of the res in the subscribe. Or look at the f12 tab network to see what data the server I returning